# Should I use final double or final float?

Tags: java, double, final

If I'm looking to store the number 99.89 into a variable. Would I be better off storing it in a final double, or a final float?

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Sorry, Java

Comment: What ***precision*** is necessary when you use the number?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 2 decimal points

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve. There is no generic, broad, one-size fits all answer to the title question you've asked (or the one in the body of your post, either).

Comment: `final` is irrelevant here. The only things that are relevant here are the precision and range that you require and the space you can afford, and only you know these things.

Answer (score 1):

With only four decimal digits, either float or double should work. (The only requirement seems to be to "store a value" in a variable.)

The IEEE floating point types are an *approximation* of a decimal value. If you need an exact decimal representation, then Java `BigDecimal` class might be a better choice.

Again, if the only requirement is to store a value in a variable, then I don't think it matters which datatype you use. We could even store the value as a String.

The datatype only matters if the code is going to do something else with the value.

Answer (score 1):

Whether `float` or `double`,they both have accuracy problem.So,if you'd be better to use `BigDecimal` to avoid loss of accuracy.